# Problem with printing nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature

I have a question about the nomenclature. I used the following code to generate the nomenclature. The code works well on one of my computers and on overleaf. But it **does not work** on another computer.

I got the errors:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? I would appreciate your help. I am using texstudio.

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs,serif]{wiley-article}

\immediate\write18{%
    makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls -t \jobname.nlg \jobname.nlo%
}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Roman symbols}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\item[\textbf{Greek symbols}]}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{\item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{
    }}}}%
}
\newcommand{\nomP}[1][]{\nomenclature[A#1]}
\newcommand{\nomG}[1][]{\nomenclature[B#1]}
\newcommand{\nomSub}[1][]{\nomenclature[C#1]}
\newcommand{\nomSuper}[1][]{\nomenclature[D#1]}
%% the follwing is for two column for nomenclature
\usepackage{verbatim}%to make comments
\usepackage{multicol}%for multiple columns
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
{\section*{\nomname}}
{\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\nomname}]}
    {}{}
    \appto\endthenomenclature{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pc}

%
%
\begin{document}

This is the main text.//

%
\printnomenclature

\nomP[1]{$A$}{Frequency factor}
\nomP[2]{$B$}{Factor}


\end{document}
```